# При вводе большого значения a, происходит переполнение. Как дальше работает программа? На месте a,b возникают неверные значения. Что происходит с a?

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, ввод, переполнение

```
/*
Разработка программы обмена местами двух целочисленных
ячеек памяти без использования дополнительный памяти.
Программа должна запросить у пользователя два целый числа, затем
выполнить реализованный алгоритм по шагам, показывая содержимое ячеек
памяти до первого шага и после каждого шага. Во время выполнения данного
алгоритма могут возникать целочисленные переполнения ячеек, при написании
алгоритма этот случай должен быть учтён.

*/



#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    long a, b;
    std::cout << "Введите целочисленное значение переменной a: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "\nВведите целочисленное значение переменной b: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "\nИзначальное значение a: " << a;
    std::cout << "\nИзначальное значение b: " << b;
    a = a + b;

    std::cout << "\nЗначение a после первой операции: " << a;

    b = b - a;

    std::cout << "\nЗначение b после первой операции: " << b;

    b = -b;

    std::cout << "\nЗначение b после второй операции: " << b;

    a = a - b;

    std::cout << "\nЗначение a после второй операции: " << a;

    std::cout << "\n\nЗначение a после обмена ячеек: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Значение b после обмена ячеек: " << b << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Скажите, что вам здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1331269/195342 было неясно, что вы создали новый аккаунт и опять задаете тот же вопрос?

Comment: все описано в вопросе

Answer (score 3):

Вот описание того, как ведет себя оператор `>>` при вводе чего-то **очень** большого:

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set. For signed integers, if extraction results in the value **too large** or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` (respectively) is written and **failbit flag is set**. For unsigned integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is written and failbit flag is set.

Т.е. у вас в `a` помещается `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`, после чего устанавливается флаг `fail`, и дальнейшие чтения просто не выполняются. Т.е. в `b` будет тот мусор, который там был изначально.